# How can I implement Dijkstra's Algorithm in T-SQL to find the shortest route through my data-points?

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables, cross-apply

- I have the following table containing n bins in a warehouse and their coordinate points on a map.
- I would like to find the distance between every point in the list.
- I have attempted to use a `pivot`, `cross apply`, `cross join`, etc and ultimately get nowhere close to the intended result (typically get an error) so I will refrain from posting my code here..
- Below is my sample data and my desired output.
- ...and once found, how can I insert the shortest path/route into a new temporary-table?

---

**Sample Data:**

| BinCoord | BinNumb |
| --- | --- |
| (27,1) | S |
| (18,2) | D1 |
| (24,2) | B1 |
| (15,23) | E20 |

**Desired output:**

(Distances are placeholders, not actual values). I'm not too bothered about how the `BinPath` is represented: e.g. a To and From column would also work fine.

| Distance | BinPath |
| --- | --- |
| 3.32 | S-D1 |
| 5.54 | D1-B1 |
| 7.62 | B1-E20 |
| 2.23 | D1-E20 |

---

I would assume this needs to be in some sort of loop or maybe is achievable in a pivot with some dynamic SQL. My apologies for not having a better attempted path.

---

**Here is what I tried:**

It takes my sample data and apparently does nothing because I don't understand what I need to do. My aim was to create a matrix and then do some sort of loop or `cross apply` to find distances between all points in the matrix.

```sql
SELECT
    D1.[BinCoord],
    D1.[BinNum]
FROM
    ##Djik3 D1
    CROSS JOIN ##Djik3 D2
WHERE
    D1.BinCoord = D2.BinCoord
    AND
    D1.BinNum = D2.BinNum
```

Comment: Exactly what RDBMS are you using? Does it have built-in support for spatial-types? (aka geometry/geospatial types?) (most modern RDBMS do) - if it does then you should use that built-in functionality for computing distances etc.

Comment: _"so I will refrain from posting my code here"_ - no, you **should** still post it so that we can let you know where you're going wrong.

Comment: I am using SSMS on SQL Server 12.0 I will update the question and post my code, it apparently does nothing to my sample data.

Comment: It is not normally necessary to find _every_ distance between _every_ nose, in SQL you can efficiently find the nearest point or implement many path optimisations using spatial queries in SQL directly

Comment: @ChrisSchaller My ultimate goal is to find the shortest path between all points. I am taking a step by step approach probably far from the optimal method because I am a beginner. If you had advice on how to achieve this aim using a better method please feel free to share

Comment: @JacobRoutier _"My ultimate goal is to find the shortest path between all points"_ - uhhh, are you familiar with the Travelling Salesman Problem? ...or at least Dijkstra's Algorithm?

Comment: research `shortest distance manhattan`

Comment: Microsoft doesn't refer to SQL Server versions by number, only their marketing name - version 12.0 is SQL Server 2014 which is _almost_ obsolete now - is there any way you can update to a more modern version?

Comment: @jsotola _"shortest distance manhattan"_ - ah yes, that's the name of my favourite cocktail (i.e. the most nearest one)

Comment: @Dai Yes, I am actually trying to implement Dijkstra's Algorithm but having a hard time finding solutions out there already so trying to work through my own. And no, unfortunately I am not able to upgrade. It is an Azure server and I am not the admin

Comment: @JacobRoutier By "Azure" do you mean Azure SQL - or Azure Managed Instance? If the former, then the "12.0" displayed in Object Explorer is a lie: it's _always_ reported as 12.0 for some reason, the effective "real" version is somewhere in-between SQL Server 2019 and SQL Server 2022.

Comment: @Dai Azure SQL so yes I guess it will show 12.0 regardless

Comment: [Here's a loop-based implementation of Dijkstra's in T-SQL implemented in 2006](http://hansolav.net/blog/ImplementingDijkstrasAlgorithmUsingTSQL.aspx) but I _do not_ recommend this approach today given that we now have support for self-referential CTEs and Graph Tables (with node pattern matching, kinda like a good-enough implementation of neo4j's graph query language). If you're able to create new DB objects, have you considered creating a [Graph Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-architecture) representation of your data as a starting point?

Comment: @Dai Thank you so much, I will look into the link. And yes, I do have permissions to create new objects but this is the first I am hearing of a graph table. Looks like what I would need so I will give it a try. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is the same in later versions, expect that we can use built in functionality.

- For just simple 2D distance this is probably going to have a similar level of performance

We can build your table using a CTE to first parse the `BinCoords` into numeric values, if you have a massive amount of records then you might compute this into its own temp table first (or build the CTE logic into the query that build the `#Djik3` temp table):

```
-- Format the data first!
WITH BinCoords as (
    SELECT 
          BinCoord
        , BinNumb
        , X = CAST(SUBSTRING(BinCoord, 2, Fx1.Comma - 2) as real)
        , Y = CAST(SUBSTRING(BinCoord, Fx1.Comma + 1, LEN(BinCoord) - Fx1.Comma - 1) as real)
    FROM #Djik3 d
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(',', BinCoord) as Comma) as Fx1
)
SELECT 
      [From] = src.BinNumb
    , [To] = tgt.BinNumb
    , [BinPath] = CONCAT(src.BinNumb,'-',tgt.BinNumb)
    , [Distance] = SQRT(((src.X - tgt.X)*(src.X - tgt.X))+((src.Y - tgt.Y)*(src.Y - tgt.Y)))
FROM BinCoords src
CROSS JOIN BinCoords tgt
WHERE src.BinNumb > tgt.BinNumb
```

| From | To | BinPath | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S | D1 | S-D1 | 9.055385138137417 |
| E20 | D1 | E20-D1 | 21.213203435596427 |
| S | B1 | S-B1 | 3.1622776601683795 |
| D1 | B1 | D1-B1 | 6 |
| E20 | B1 | E20-B1 | 22.847319317591726 |
| S | E20 | S-E20 | 25.059928172283335 |

*Using simple Pythagoras formula to calculate the distance*

The tricky thing with a `CROSS JOIN` is that you will get all the results of `A-B` and `B-A`, including `B-B` and `A-A`. The simple way to only get the *unique* path combinations is to use a `less than`, or `greater than` comparison on the node identifier.

- I have used `A > B` to get the *larger* node first to match your expectation, but `A < B` would have worked equally well.

See this Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/74cbba/3

---

### UPDATE: Dijkstras Algorithm needs the reverse paths too!

If the purpose of computing the node distances is to use *Dijkstras Algorithm* to find the shortest route between the nodes, then we need the reverse paths to, so the only path to exclude in the SQL is `A-A`, for that we change the filter:

```
FROM BinCoords src
CROSS JOIN BinCoords tgt
WHERE src.BinNumb <> tgt.BinNumb
```

*Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/74cbba/1*

| From | To | Path | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | S | D1-S | 9.05538513813742 |
| B1 | S | B1-S | 3.16227766016838 |
| E20 | S | E20-S | 25.0599281722833 |
| S | D1 | S-D1 | 9.05538513813742 |
| B1 | D1 | B1-D1 | 6 |
| E20 | D1 | E20-D1 | 21.2132034355964 |
| S | B1 | S-B1 | 3.16227766016838 |
| D1 | B1 | D1-B1 | 6 |
| E20 | B1 | E20-B1 | 22.8473193175917 |
| S | E20 | S-E20 | 25.0599281722833 |
| D1 | E20 | D1-E20 | 21.2132034355964 |
| B1 | E20 | B1-E20 | 22.8473193175917 |

---

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, I really appreciate it. I am implementing it now and will comment back if I run into any issues.

Comment: It doesn't actually run dijkstras but this table helps you get there. Storing your data in a more code friendly manner with Ids and discrete values for X and Y ordinates, or using geometry data types will make this sort of logic easier in the future.

Comment: Worked brilliantly! Thank you. Also yes you are correct but this format is exactly what I need as inputs for the rest of my code.